# python one liner + compare numbers

Tags: linux, python, environment-variables

please advice what is wrong with my syntax ( I use it in my bash script )

```
export CALC=3.4373
python -c 'print CALC > 2.2'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 1, in ?

NameError: name 'CALC' is not defined
```

**should get True**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `''`. It doesn't parse bash variables.

What you want is: `python -c "print ${CALC} > 2.2"`

Comment: alternately `python -c 'import os; print os.environ["CALC"] > 2.2'`